Elstodt: Maß- und Integrationstheorie: Exercise I.4.2
I am studying Measure Theory using the book by Jürgen Elstrodt and there is one exercise I am struggling with.
The author mentions the following property of $\sigma$-Algebras: $\sigma(\mathfrak{E}) = \bigcup_{\mathfrak{F} \subset \mathfrak{E}, \mathfrak{F} \text{ countable}} \sigma(\mathfrak{F})$ where $\sigma(\mathfrak{E})$ and $\sigma(\mathfrak{F})$ are the $\sigma$-Algebras generated by $\mathfrak{E}$ and $\mathfrak{F}$, respectively.
The task is to write down a similar statement for $\mathfrak{S}$, the $\sigma$-Ring generated by $\mathfrak{E}$, and prove that for every $A \in \mathfrak{S}$, there is a sequence $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ in $\mathfrak{E}$ such that $A \subset \bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$.
The first part is easy (a proof can be found here):
$\mathfrak{S} = \bigcup_{\mathfrak{F} \subset \mathfrak{E}, \mathfrak{F} \text{ countable}} \mathfrak{S}(\mathfrak{F})$ where $\mathfrak{S}(\mathfrak{F})$ is the $\sigma$-Ring generated by $\mathfrak{F}$.
But how can we prove the other statement for every $A \in \mathfrak{S}$? I would appreciate some help on getting started.
Thanks a lot!

Hint: Show that the set of $A$, such that there is a sequence $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ in $\mathfrak{E}$ such that $A \subset \bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ is a $\sigma$-ring containing $\mathfrak{E}$.
Thus this $\sigma$-ring contains $\mathfrak{S}$.
Another way using the fact that $\mathfrak{S}(\mathfrak{E}) = \bigcup_{\mathfrak{F} \subset \mathfrak{E}, \mathfrak{F} \text{ countable}} \mathfrak{S}(\mathfrak{F})$ would be to find for a given $A$ a countable set $\mathfrak{F}\subseteq \mathfrak{E}$ such that $A\in \mathfrak{S}(\mathfrak{F})$ and note that for any countable set $\mathfrak{F}$ and $B\in\mathfrak{S}(\mathfrak{F})$ we have $B\subseteq \bigcup_{C\in\mathfrak{F}}C$. This follows from the fact that $\{D\mid D\subseteq \bigcup_{C\in\mathfrak{F}}C\}$ is a $\sigma$-ring.

Ok, so if $\mathfrak{F} \neq \emptyset$, then $\emptyset \in {D | D \subset \bigcup_{c \in \mathfrak{F}} C}$ and $A \setminus B \subset A$ can be covered by the same union as $A$. For a countable union we just take the union of the covers of all those sets, so that proves the fact that ${D | D \subset \bigcup_{c \in \mathfrak{F}} C}$ is a $\sigma$-Ring since iIf $\mathfrak{F}=\emptyset$, then this is trivial. And this $\sigma$-Ring also contains $\mathfrak{F}$, and thus $\mathfrak{S}(\mathfrak{F})$, which proves the result correct?

It seems you are mixing up the two hints. To be more specific in the secons hint (which uses the statement you mention in the OP): For any subset $F$ the set ${A\mid A\subseteq F}$ forms a $\sigma$-ideal. We use this for $F=\bigcup_{D\in\mathfrak{F}}D$. Noting that $\mathfrak{F}$ is countable, we have that $\bigcup_{D\in\mathfrak{F}}D\in \mathfrak{S}(\mathfrak{E})$. Secondly, since $A\in  \mathfrak{S}(\mathfrak{F})$, we have $A\subseteq \bigcup_{D\in\mathfrak{F}}D$, since this is true for any set in $\mathfrak{S}(\mathfrak{F})$.

Ok, maybe I should have given my sets different names. I just wanted to provide a proof sketch for why ${D |D \subset \bigcup_{C \in \mathfrak{F}} C}$ is a $\sigma$-Ring. Clearly, this $\sigma$-Ring also contains $\mathfrak{F}$. So ${D |D \subset \bigcup_{C \in \mathfrak{F}} C}$ contains $\sigma(\mathfrak{F})$, which is why the set $A \in \sigma(\mathfrak{F})$ has the desired propery. Or am I missing anything?

this argument seems fine.
